# How do I use ASPX on Apache

Tags: asp.net, xampp

I am using xampp and I need to use ASPX to install an Stack Overflow clone on my localhost.

I read there was an module for it but I can't download/install it and if available does it work on an Linux OS host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASPX under Linux, you must use the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) project.
It has an ASP.NET implementation, that you can use it with Apache using [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: Mono is cross platform. http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html. Note: you can use ASPX even with the XSP server, without installing apache.